# Unity3d 5 - default assets RollerBall+MultipurposeCameraRig rotation/tilt problems

Tags: unity

I started a new Unity3d 3D project. I imported the Player, Camera and Prototyping assets.

I placed a FloorPrototype64x01x64 and scaled it *2 on all axis. I reset it to 0,0,0 position and rotation.

I placed the RollerBall prefab and also reset it. I then set Y position to 0.5 to move it up on top of the floor.

I placed the MultipurposeCameraRig and its Transform values are all reset to begin with. I can see it has a child Pivot object with 2 in Y and -3 in Z (making it a point above and behind the Rigs transform). This looks good.

Since the camera has a script to target the object with the "Player" tag, it gets a hold on the RollerBall which has that tag.

When i start the player i can move the ball around with the arrow keys. The thing is, even though i go straight "up" the camera tilts a bit after less than a half rotation of the ball. The camera stays behind (on z axis) no matter what way i'm going. Once i play around with it, the camera get more wacky and if i stop pressing any keys and let the ball speed slowly decrease, then the camera goes nuts and start turning around all axis - bringing it on the side and below the floor.

I tried playing a round a bit with the camera both to fix this bug and to make the camera stay behind the ball (like a normal first/third person view/race-car view where you see the back of the character). I do the following:

On the auto cam script i enable Follow Velocity, and i disable Follow Tilt. On the cameras RidigBody i freeze X and Z rotation.

Now i get the camera to stay behind the ball like i want - i can keep the "up" key pressed and use the "left" and "right" to turn. This behaves like a normal Racing game.

But I still got the same weird behavior. When i start the game, the camera tilts slighty to the right and if i slow down the ball, the camera goes wonky. Since i froze the Z and X it stays level with the floor, but it twists and turns around the Y axis, making it impossible to navigate property. Once i get some speed on the ball again, the camera seems to behave again.

**TL;DR
The MultipurposeCameraRig's rotation seem to not work at slow Player speeds, how can i fix this?**

Comment: can you post a minimum project or video that re-create the problem? IMHO it's still to hard to imagine everything from you explanantion, especially with your object/prefab properties and your scripts. Because the problem may lies anywhere

Comment: It's just using the basic assets/prefabs. I can try and make a video when i get home...